# Google Translate and the Watched Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know whether it is a *bug*.
I always met the problem that some tags of my "Watched Tags" always disappeared for no reason.

Today I finally found why it occurs (I always browse Stack Overflow with [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate#Browser_integration). Due to I am not a native speaker, it will be faster to understand the meaning of a question with Google Translate):

To make it happen, there is a small example of a GIF image:

[image: tr6Zmq.gif]

At the beginning:

[image]

In the end (`Java` has been added, but `selenium` and `go` disappear).

[image]

Step:

1. Open the Google Translate (in my example, I translate the page to Chinese)
2. After that, when you add any tag, another tag will disappear.

Comment: Use of external plugins and userscripts are not supported. Perhaps disable the conflicting plugin temporarily and try again?

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yeah, Maybe just give a tip for other people who also used Google Translation.Don't use translation when edit tags.

Comment: I tried it without plugins but it also occured.So I think Google Translation cause this issue.

Comment: Yes, it's not surprising that Google Translate would interfere with JavaScript code running on the site. I don't see how this is a Stack Overflow bug.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I removed the `BUG` tag.

Comment: Machine translation is known to produce completely incomprehensible results. How does that work? Does it work better for the content on Stack Overflow?